# Does evolution affect EV training?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I wish to EV train an excadril. Can I EV train a drilbur and expect the effort values to carry over without consequence?  Also, one I get all of my effort value in place, am I free to train anywhere without screwing up the EVs I've already got?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Yes your EV values carry over when you evolve.  If you max out your drilbur before evolving,  Excadril will have those same EV values.

2.) As long as you don't use any items that alter the EV values,  you can train your heart out wherever you wish.